# Вопрос к бородатым дядям от новичка с большим желанием изучать

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, reactjs, frontend

Доброе время суток всем кто читает!
Самое что не понятно, React используется для создания пользовательского интерфейса, НО я так понял там и логику пишут или как? Как он стоит на Node? Чтоб полноценно писать сайты или приложения мне надо знать Node?

Понимаю, вопросы для Вас пустяковые, но для меня нет)

Comment: Слишком много вопросов в одном посте :) Никто,  кроме вас, не скажет, хватит ли ваших знаний для разработки чего-то.  Единственный способ узнать - попробовать.

Comment: Согласен, много было вопросов. Поправил

Comment: Ок.  Но просьбу накидать ссылок лучше убрать.  Тут так не принято,  приветствуются полноценные ответы (и вопросы,  которые таких ответов требуют)

Comment: Спасибо, убрал)

Comment: Недавно от mail.ru статья хорошая была про это на хабре: https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/340922/

Comment: Спасибо за статью, довольно познавательно, есть куда подумать.